# Is $\mathbb{F}_{81}$ a field extension of $\mathbb{F}_{27}$?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Is $\mathbb{F}_{81}$ a field extension of $\mathbb{F}_{27}$? If it is, what is $[\mathbb{F}_{81}:\mathbb{F}_{27}]$? In this case, $\mathbb{F}_{81}$ means a field with 81 elements. I know like $\mathbb{F}_{81}$ is the splitting field of $x^{81-1}=1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$, right? But what next? Or since $81$ is not a power of $27$, $\mathbb{F}_{81}$ is not an field extension of $\mathbb{F}_{27}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose it is, then

$$[\Bbb F_{81}:\Bbb F_3]=[\Bbb F_{81}:\Bbb F_{27}]\,[\Bbb F_{27}:\Bbb F_3]$$

Now, $\;[\Bbb F_{p^n}:\Bbb F_p]=n\;$ *always*, so what can you deduce from the above?

You can also try to prove the general claim: $\;\Bbb F_{p^n}\;$ is a subfield of $\;\Bbb F_{p^m}\;$ iff $\;n\,\mid\,m\;$

Comment: So, Galois group of $\mathbb{F}_{81}$ over $\mathbb{F}_{27}$ does not exist?

Comment: @Kelan There is not even a field extension in this case, so it is moot to talk of Galois group...

Comment: I'm not very confident with my understanding of Galois group. So, if Galois group of $E$ over $F$ exists, $E$ must be a field extension of $F$, right? Thus, we can have an automorphism.

Comment: @Kelan I'm not following you: for us to talk of automorphisms in a field extension $\;E/F\;$ there must be, to begin with, a field extensions $\;E/F\;$ , of course! It's like trying to talk about the continuity of a function without actually having a function at all! In this case, you have two fields none of which is a **field extension** of the other one (though both are extensions of their common prime field), so the idea of "automorphism" cannot exist here related to a **non-existing** field extension.

Comment: There is a question asked like "prove or disprove: Galois group of $\mathbb{F}_{81}$ over $\mathbb{F}_{27}$ is cyclic." I was wondering too. If this group does not exist, how can prove or disprove is cyclic.

Comment: @Kelan You can always write "the question is moot" as written above, or say "the group doesn't even exist because..." . I  really can't say what the intention of the question was, though I suspect that either whoever wrote it got confused with the powers of $\;3\;$ he took or else he wanted students to write something about not existing a field extension here and etc.

Comment: OK. I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

To be a field extension, you must in particular be a vector space, and the general theory of vector spaces (existence of a basis) tells us that the order of $V$ must be a power of the order of $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Any extension field of $\mathbb{F}_{27}$ is an $\mathbb{F}_{27}$-vector space. In particular, the finite degree extensions must have order a power of 27. Thus $\mathbb{F}_{81}$ is not an extension field.